# GitHub Codespace Debugger

Tags: node.js, github, npm, backend, codespaces

So I'm developing a web app and programming it via vs code and my github codespace. But for some reason I can't start the back-end server. I always get the error: EADDRINUSE
What I've tried:

1. Find programms that block the port and kill them, nothing found
2. change the port
3. restart VS code, restart the codespace
4. Create new codespace and install the npm packages

If you need me to provide more information, please just ask.

As already described, the listing above. I hoped to clear out what ever blocked the port but some how it didn't work.
I was able to start the frontend normally on port 8080. But for some reason when trying to start the backend on 3000 its blocked.
The command I use for starting the backend is: npm run start